# Call Windows 10 Desktop Notifications from a website?

Tags: javascript, windows

Chrome 47 has removed Desktop Notifications... is there any method of calling the new Windows 10 Desktop Notification from a website, possibly using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [HTML5 Notification API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/notifications/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) that is still a draft spec currently. So far only webkit and firefox implements the draft spec. However, there is [a plugin](https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications) to sort of polyfill the API.